# How to filter order with today and yesterday date in django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I want to get total sales of order by today, yesterday, quarterly and yearly.
And here is my code:

```
today = Order.objects.filter(created_at__date=request.data['today']).aggregate(Sum('total_price'))
yesterday = Order.objects.filter(created_at__date=request.data['yesterday']).aggregate(Sum('total_price'))
quarterly = Order.objects.filter(created_at__range=[request.data['quarterly'], request.data['today']]).aggregate(
    Sum('total_price'))
yearly = Order.objects.filter(created_at__range=[request.data['yearly'], request.data['today']]).aggregate(
    Sum('total_price'))
response_data = {
    "today_sales": today,
    "yesterday_sales": yesterday,
    "quarterly_sales": quarterly,
    "yearly_sales": yearly
}
return Response(response_data)
```

But this code give errors for today and yesterday date.
But I can successfully retrieve quarterly and yearly sales.
So please help me with today and yesterday sales to retrieve.

Comment: Can you post error trace log?

Comment: What does the data in `request.data` look like? You should be able to perform all of these aggregations in a single query

Comment: This is my request.data ={
      today: moment(),
      yesterday: moment().subtract('1', 'days'),
      quarterly: moment().subtract(3, "months"),
      yearly: moment().subtract(12, "months")
    }

Comment: You're sending `moment` objects in an AJAX request? Won't they be coming though in `request.data` as strings?

Comment: They are goind like this = '2021-02-25T08:28:50.199Z'

Comment: @SACHINKUMAR: but why? The Django server knows what the current date/datetime is.

Comment: I don't know so

Comment: @SACHINKUMAR your first step should be to clean the incoming data: convert the strings to datetime objects using `django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime` or better yet use a form/serializer to do it for you

Comment: I have convert it, but still it cannot be compared against created_at__date. It sitll return null sales

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `date` object for today and yesterday. You can use a `timedelta` object to obtain the day before:

```
from django.utils.timzone import now
from datetime import timedelta

cur_date=now().date()

today = Order.objects.filter(
    created_at__date=cur_date
).aggregate(Sum('total_price'))

yesterday = Order.objects.filter(
    created_at__date=cur_date-timedelta(days=1)
).aggregate(Sum('total_price'))
```

Comment: This code also return null for toaday and yesterday.

Comment: @SACHINKUMAR: are you working with a MySQL database? You need to load timezone info in the database https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/can-not-extract-filter-a-date-time-field-when-time-zones-are-enabled.html

Comment: @SACHINKUMAR: it will also return `NULL`/`None`, if there are *no records* for today or yesterday, since a database returns `NULL` for an empty aggregate.

Comment: Ok thanks! I successfully load the timezone files and it is now working.